# Using thousands of JSON files to build a database. I need some direction

Tags: json, database, mongodb, nosql, couchdb

### Intro

I've been a MySQL user for many--many--years and this will be my first time ever venturing outside of MySQL. I ask for patience, please, as I may struggle trying to explain my situation.

### Situation

Over the last ten years, I've downloaded statistical data in `JSON` format for a sports team. The data is organized by `players` and `matches`, with each `player` being saved in separate file and each `match` saved in a separate file. I would like to take all of the data I've collected and dump it into a database, however, I would prefer the database to be either `MongoDB` or `CouchDB`. This database will be used to power a historical website dedicated to this team: every player, every match and every recorded statistic.

### Questions

Does it make sense to move away from MySQL in this situation?

Between MongoDB and CouchDB, which platform has a steeper learning curve?

Is there a different platform better suited for this situation?

Are there any areas of concern to be mindful of while learning the nuances of different database platforms that you recommend?

--

Any advice would be very much appreciated. Thank you very much for your time. Cheers

Comment: why are you trying to load the data into MongoDB or Couch (Document database). What is your use case here?

Comment: This question is honest but I suspect it will be closed by moderators shortly because it seeks opinion, not an answer to a specific question.
That said:  If you have a pile of JSON, use MongoDB.   ;-)

Comment: Little more specifically, what are you going to do with the data? What kind of operations / queries? How much data and what is its nature? Based upon your application needs you would model the data; do you have a data model?. Tabular data (SQL) and Document based (NoSQL MongoDB) has their own advantages. Also, your situation (e.g., if you know using SQL database well, why not use it, and save time and effort of learning). If you already have a preference about some databases, what research have you done so far about those?

Comment: @prasad_ I’m going to build a website dedicated to the history of this team. Every player, every match and every statistic recorded.

Comment: @asd To power a historical website for this team. It’ll document every player, match and recorded statistic.

Comment: I'd use CouchDB only if you rely on its replication protocol or Erlang's concurrency, e.g. if you're building an offline-first app using client-side sync with PouchDB, if you're planning to replicate data between different CouchDB instances or if you'll have thousands of clients directly connected and syncing with the CouchDB. 
For a typical client-server app, I'd rather go with MongoDB.